# Where is the autocomplete "Committed by typing the following characters" option in VS2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

I don't want a "space", for example, to trigger auto-complete.

It's not where it used to be in VS2010: (Tools - Options - Text Editor - C# - Intellisense). ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcf2zk43.aspx)) and I couldn't find it anywhere else.

Comment: @DownVoter Care to explain why?

Comment: I have this option provided by my copy of VA-X: http://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W204#accept   That page also shows where the related Visual Studio option was (and no longer is)

Comment: What's strange is you can still find options for this for other languages, just not C#. C++ has the full character list and Javascript has "Only use Tab or Enter to commit".

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTRL + ALT + Spacebar to toggle IntelliSense Suggestion Mode. That way when you hit space it wont auto-complete the suggestion. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2012/05/01/9943045.aspx

Comment: Thanks. But I do want completion mode, but only by certain keys. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: Here in 2022 with VS2022 this obscure trick seems to work to toggle whether "." will activate it. @ispiro it doesn't actually turn _off_ the suggestion mode, it just seems to change what says "yes". Tab still says "yes". It's very strange this option is missing from Tools/Options for C# Intellisense though.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look and I think they removed this option in 2015. What you can do is simply press `Right Arrow` to cancel the commit. In VC++ these options are still available for some reason.